# Python: is there a pythonic "fetch and update" expression?

Tags: python, expression

How many times have you seen something like this:

```
tmp = reference
reference = new_value
return tmp
```

It doesn't *really* bother me, but is there some Pythonic shorthand to accomplish the same thing without the temporary variable?

*(I envision something like `return shift(reference, new_value)`...)*

Answer (score 5):

IIUC:

```
>>> a=1
>>> b=2
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> a
2
>>> b
1
>>>
```

Swapping variables can work as expected in this case

So basically logic written:

```
a,b=b,a
^ ^ ^ ^
1 2 2 1

2 1
^ ^
1 2
```

Comment: This is nifty, but it's an assignment _statement_, not an assignment _expression_: i.e. you can't do `return a,b=b,a`.  I may have to wait for Python 3.8 and `:=` (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Answer (score 0):

Tuple swap is the simplest one:

```
if x = 5 and y = 10
```

then

```
x,y = y,x  will swap their values:

x = 10
y = 5
```

Comment: Well, how's that not mine?

Comment: ...and it's also not an expression, as requested in the OP